# Calculating Exponential Moving Average In Access VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

In Excel VBA, I have a working function to calculate an Exponentially Weighted Moving Average, following http://www.value-at-risk.net/exponentially-weighted-moving-average-ewma/

I want to convert this function to Access VBA to use with some data I have in Access.

I have data of the form:

```
BucketDate     InterpRate
8/17/2015      5.56992228328638E-03 
8/18/2015      5.64693660341032E-03 
8/19/2015      5.72395092353427E-03 
8/20/2015      5.80096524365821E-03 
8/21/2015      5.87797956378215E-03 
8/22/2015      5.9549938839061E-03 
8/23/2015      6.03200820403004E-03 
8/24/2015      6.10902252415399E-03 
  ...              ...
```

for 76 datapoints. The VBA subroutine is as follows:

```
Function EWMA(InterpRate As Range, Lambda As Double, _
                 MarkDate As Date, MaturityDate As Date) As Double

    Dim vZeros() As Variant
    Dim Price1 As Double, Price2 As Double
    Dim SumWtdRtn As Double
    Dim I As Long
    Dim m As Double

    Dim LogRtn As Double, RtnSQ As Double, WT As Double, WtdRtn As Double

vZeros = InterpRate

m = Month(MaturityDate) - Month(MarkAsOfDate)

For I = 2 To UBound(vZeros, 1)

    Price1 = Exp(-vZeros(I - 1, 1) * (m / 12))

    Price2 = Exp(-vZeros(I, 1) * (m / 12))

    LogRtn = Log(Price1 / Price2)

    RtnSQ = LogRtn ^ 2

    WT = (1 - Lambda) * Lambda ^ (I - 2)

    WtdRtn = WT * RtnSQ

    SumWtdRtn = SumWtdRtn + WtdRtn

Next I

EWMA = SumWtdRtn ^ (1 / 2)

End Function
```

However, I cannot pass InterpRate into an array to use to calculate the exponentially weighted moving average. How can I change this in order to calculate the exponential moving average?

Comment: You can't assign a Double to an array in Excel VBA either. This must not be the working Excel VBA function.

Comment: Sorry, it is working in Excel, I just corrected that first line, thank you

Comment: Ah, got it. What are you going to pass into the function from Access? A recordset? In Excel the `Range.Value` property (`Value` is the default property so it's what you're calling when you don't supply a property) can be passed a Variant to make a two-dim array. But there is not `Range` property in Access.

Comment: If you will arrange the data in an array and pass that in place of the range, you can take advantage of this info: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx.  Or, pass a recordset (DBA for most of us).  Either way, you have some learning to do for the methods of Access.